# Remote Desktop Connection keeps timing out

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

I use RDP to connect to a server, and I leave it connected while I work, but it always keeps disconnecting me - I have other servers that don't do this... is there a setting somewhere that I need to set? What is this setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably best suited for ServerFault, but I would check the RDP Idle disconnect and other timers.  See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754272.